# Add restrictions to S3 Upload from Amazon Web Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a mobile application and a web application.
Both applications upload images and videos to Amazon S3 Directly using the appropriate SDK.

Is there a way i can add restrictions like file size or file type to a bucket from AWS console itself not from the web/mobile application client?